# How to combine No Follow and Target Blank Attributes For Site Links

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink, nofollow

On my site I have banners and a forum.  I want the links to be nofollow and Target Blank, so I need to combine these attributes, but I'm not sure which is correct:

Should it be written as:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank"
```

Or is this the correct way:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"
```

Which way will do this correctly and ensure they're no follow in the Search engines?

Comment: Position of attributes doesn't matter. So you answer is both are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a correct order that attributes should be listed in when linking external files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646653/is-there-a-correct-order-that-attributes-should-be-listed-in-when-linking-extern)