# href style rel - What is the right order when linking a CSS stylesheet to an HTML file

Tags: html, css

When you link a CSS stylesheet to an HTML file you have to use:
     
Is there something wrong if I will use for    href ,    type    and    rel a different order?

Should they be written in this order? If yes, is there any explanation for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646653/is-there-a-correct-order-that-attributes-should-be-listed-in-when-linking-extern

Comment: "Is there something wrong if I will use for href , type and rel a different order?" — Do you have any reason to think that might be the case? Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes can be in any order.

But, the best way to link CSS is before scripts that has to be included in page. Also the format for linking CSS should be as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

This is the most practiced way of linking CSS to HTML.

Why this Format ?

1. We need to set the relationship between the document to be linked and link added document(rel). As this is stylesheet (rel="stylesheet").
2. Next, the type of document. In this, the file to be added is a text file and is of the type css. So (type="text/css")
3. Finally the url of the file to be included.

Hope this is helpful.